# Useless low entropy answers on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, answers, flags, useless-answers

Using the data dump I came up with a list of "answers" containing no useful text. Those answers are all just noise and should be deleted by a moderator.

And instead of spending the next days with flagging them for moderator attention one by one, here they are:

- [answer #1098444](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785927/how-to-build-dynamic-data-entry-forms-in-a-wpf-application/1098444#1098444)
- [answer #1432179](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200268/qt4-in-visual-studio-2008-moc-ed-files-get-excluded-from-build/1432179#1432179)
- [answer #11988](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986/why-does-sqlite3-ruby-1-2-2-not-work-on-os-x/11988#11988)
- [answer #460200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460183/how-to-jquery-div-toggle-more-dynamic/460200#460200)
- [answer #460190](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460183/how-to-jquery-div-toggle-more-dynamic/460190#460190)
- [answer #1064472](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802374/how-to-limit-string-word-count-in-xslt-1-0/1064472#1064472)
- [answer #460219](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460183/how-to-jquery-div-toggle-more-dynamic/460219#460219)
- [answer #890513](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890487/is-software-development-a-discipline-of-engineering-or-a-discipline-of-arts/890513#890513)
- [answer #1378149](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311722/recursive-function-to-add-sum-of-sequence-of-numbers-and-the-sums-thereof/1378149#1378149)
- [answer #1379631](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590257/determine-remote-client-ip-address-for-java-rmi-call/1379631#1379631)
- [answer #497618](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73308/true-timeout-on-lwpuseragent-request-method/497618#497618)
- [answer #1245897](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230109/questions-on-differences-from-asp-net-2-0-to-asp-net-3-5-mvc/1245897#1245897)
- [answer #904196](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578469/error-compiling-program-in-visual-studio-2008/904196#904196)
- [answer #1788626](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265563/cookie-blocked-popup-in-ie/1788626#1788626)
- [answer #404896](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125612/how-do-i-apply-css-to-second-level-menu-items/404896#404896)
- [answer #1678917](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926/crystal-reports-2008-inprocserver-tempdir-operation-not-yet-implemented/1678917#1678917)
- [answer #1687046](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing/1687046#1687046)
- [answer #1074456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482889/how-to-find-and-select-multiple-rows-with-macro-excel/1074456#1074456)
- [answer #1672759](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672662/img-upload-help/1672759#1672759)
- [answer #1386747](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works/1386747#1386747)
- [answer #1537108](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534703/event-handler/1537108#1537108)
- [answer #1365993](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-wi/1365993#1365993)
- [answer #1782880](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350634/scheduled-mail-in-asp-net/1782880#1782880)
- [answer #1583151](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361921/list-manipulation-in-c-using-linq/1583151#1583151)
- [answer #734686](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734238/how-do-i-create-a-lexer-in-python/734686#734686)
- [answer #1557162](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821108/clustered-non-clustered-index-on-unique-identifier-column-in-sql-server/1557162#1557162)
- [answer #420134](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419714/how-to-call-nunit-from-visual-studio-in-a-batch-file/420134#420134)
- [answer #1017961](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368295/how-to-get-real-string-height-in-java/1017961#1017961)
- [answer #1660346](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90203/what-is-the-difference-between-gcc-optimization-levels/1660346#1660346)
- [answer #1063363](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045922/what-do-you-prefer-for-showing-your-local-rails-projects-to-friends/1063363#1063363)
- [answer #1781469](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778030/cast-concrete-class-to-generic-base-interface/1781469#1781469)
- [answer #1023886](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023820/second-or-third-time-a-symbol-appears/1023886#1023886)
- [answer #1371787](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421945/is-it-possible-to-degrade-from-ie7-to-ie6-for-debugging-purposes/1371787#1371787)
- [answer #1754498](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209335/excel-macro-how-to-set-x-axis/1754498#1754498)
- [answer #1803580](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335020/word-wrap-in-firefox-2-0/1803580#1803580)
- [answer #669094](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391000/how-do-i-trim-date-in-plsql/669094#669094)
- [answer #1638220](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497619/testng-and-spring-3/1638220#1638220)
- [answer #1367606](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115488/what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-create-a-custom-event-log-and-event-source-durin/1367606#1367606)
- [answer #370636](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310714/how-to-check-file-types-of-uploaded-files-in-php/370636#370636)
- [answer #487021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486964/how-to-handle-stale-connections/487021#487021)
- [answer #662293](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399406/does-microsoft-access-have-full-text-search/662293#662293)
- [answer #1583796](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311936/what-is-the-difference-between-equality-and-equivalence/1583796#1583796)
- [answer #515281](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331367/sql-statement-help-select-latest-order-for-each-customer/515281#515281)
- [answer #1081870](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877428/better-approach-for-xml-creation-in-blackberry/1081870#1081870)
- [answer #1082200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623330/how-to-convert-txt-file-into-unicode/1082200#1082200)
- [answer #1556951](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090/how-to-implement-dom-ready-event-in-a-greasemonkey-script/1556951#1556951)
- [answer #361025](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces/361025#361025)
- [answer #901001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/901001#901001)
- [answer #1044451](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825023/amazon-ec2-usable-as-a-vmware-testing-platform/1044451#1044451)
- [answer #1305634](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post/1305634#1305634)
- [answer #1062660](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994513/how-to-surround-code-with-try-catch-most-elegantly/1062660#1062660)
- [answer #1404700](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854978/org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexception-with-hibernate/1404700#1404700)
- [answer #839401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839250/answer-instance-needs-to-have-a-primary-key-value-before-a-many-to-many-relatio/839401#839401)
- [answer #1132356](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132197/which-language-for-betting-sector-and-good-salary-in-gibraltar-or-malta/1132356#1132356)
- [answer #1796204](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720784/in-opencv-what-is-cvmatnd-structure-used-for/1796204#1796204)
- [answer #1552768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438418/can-web-parts-in-sharepoint-be-moved-outside-of-edit-mode-using-drag-drop/1552768#1552768)
- [answer #393988](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984/testdriven-net-is-not-running-my-setup-methods-for-mbunit/393988#393988)
- [answer #861879](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105551/what-causes-java-io-charconversionexception-with-eof-or-ishexdigit-messages-in-to/861879#861879)
- [answer #818780](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276512/what-is-the-full-for-loop-syntax-in-c-and-others-in-case-they-are-compatible/818780#818780)
- [answer #1593552](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101827/how-to-vertical-align-a-text/1593552#1593552)
- [answer #1249140](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181233/emulating-livehttpheader-in-server-side-script-or-javascript/1249140#1249140)
- [answer #1581213](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579666/scheme-how-to-take-the-first-item-in-the-list/1581213#1581213)
- [answer #969581](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932186/asp-net-change-dropdown-control-id-inside-repeater-item-dynamically/969581#969581)
- [answer #294692](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273136/multiple-domains-same-web-application-on-iis-6/294692#294692)
- [answer #240909](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107/best-refactor-to-handle-multiple-jquery-email-field-form-validation/240909#240909)
- [answer #1609816](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609532/bit-pack-int16-into-a-ushort-vb-net/1609816#1609816)
- [answer #1304199](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288059/asp-net-forms-dropdownlist-help/1304199#1304199)
- [answer #597646](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210650/validate-image-from-file-in-c/597646#597646)
- [answer #243092](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243077/can-you-disable-an-asp-validation-on-an-event-click-before-it-postbacks-and-perfo/243092#243092)
- [answer #760809](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756656/gtkmm-update-gui-from-other-thread/760809#760809)
- [answer #1422110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927978/how-do-i-find-the-current-file-in-msbuild/1422110#1422110)
- [answer #1136431](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792597/using-hql-in-nhibernate/1136431#1136431)
- [answer #467076](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466395/javascript-object-expected/467076#467076)
- [answer #541252](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412691/dynamically-generating-radiobuttonlist/541252#541252)
- [answer #955933](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout/955933#955933)
- [answer #415358](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415268/silverlight-setting-rowdetailstemplate-controls-from-rowdetailsvisibilitychanged/415358#415358)
- [answer #797462](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406504/floated-block-level-element-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-width-if-yes-how/797462#797462)
- [answer #1353467](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014547/how-to-configure-codeigniter-modrewrite-on-wamp/1353467#1353467)
- [answer #1732338](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289030/html-hyperlink-with-mouse-over-image/1732338#1732338)
- [answer #650222](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162020/fire-async-method-on-page-load-with-ajax/650222#650222)
- [answer #688761](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514609/how-to-read-multiple-records-in-xml-doc/688761#688761)
- [answer #1254131](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312/how-you-disable-the-processor-cache-on-a-powerpc-processor/1254131#1254131)
- [answer #1623945](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231690/sharepoint-web-part-vs-asp-net-user-control/1623945#1623945)
- [answer #1626657](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623560/as2-dynamically-change-flash-movie-clip-colour-onrollover/1626657#1626657)
- [answer #1708568](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055197/friendly-code-to-transition-from-page-controller-to-front-controller/1708568#1708568)
- [answer #1309719](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309580/sql-reporting-services-2005-filter-data-by-active-directory-security-group/1309719#1309719)
- [answer #1769645](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721177/jquery-validation-submit-the-form-with-javascript-with-no-validation/1769645#1769645)
- [answer #1082195](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395286/ideas-on-implementing-stack-overflow-style-comments/1082195#1082195)

Answers posted in duplicate:

- [answer #378684](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378555/wpf-maximizing-app-window-does-not-expand-controls-vertically-horizontally-it/378684#378684)
- [answer #569371](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496554/partylist-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0/569371#569371)
- [answer #492940](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492927/freetextbox-tabs-are-not-preserved-at-postback/492940#492940)

Comment: (for info, I think we've got most of them...)

Answer (score 16):

To get the list I searched for posts containing only a small amount of different characters, based on the assumption that random typing like "hgfghhgffhgfgh" usually contains the same characters over and over again. To measure this redundancy I basically calculated the [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) of all posts:

```
double calc_entropy(const std::string &txt) {
   static const double log_2 = log(2.0);
   const int sz = txt.size();
   int chars[256] = {0};

   for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
      if (txt[i] == '>' || txt[i] == '<' || txt[i] == ' ')
         continue;
      chars[(unsigned int)(unsigned char)txt[i]]++;
   }

   double H = 0.0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      if (chars[i]) {
         double p = (double)chars[i] / sz;
         H += p * log(p) / log_2;
      }
   }
   return -H;
}
```

When sorting the posts by the score calculated by this function (or minor variants of it), the problematic answers came to the top. But of course there are also false positives, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862843/replace-translate-one-char-to-many/925352#925352) or many variations of ["Yes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158639/do-you-always-use-nouns-for-class-names/158653#158653) and ["No"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874010/asp-net-web-application-5000-lines-of-code-in-1-page-acceptable/874517#874517).

Comment: length seems to be a reasonably good indicator as well.

Comment: +1 for doin' it in c++

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... in some cases there is no edit history, but in some cases it looks like the answer has been removed (usually by the OP, perhaps lacking a "delete" button). I wonder which is the greater evil - rollback (against poster) or delete (of perhaps useful content).

Comment: there's no restriction on deleting answers, though -- only some restrictions on deleting questions because of the implied auto-delete of all answers.